# Insert data At '0' index in core plot and move the graph

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have one scenario. The X-axis in graph contains values 0,300,600,900,1200,1500,1800 from right to left(opposite to actual graphs).

I have an array like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,etc.

now, i want to plot the data on the graph. For that I am using like this.

```
  [thePlot insertDataAtIndex:0 numberOfRecords:1];
```

Because I want to insert the data at index '0' always and previous values move from right to left. But it is not moving because the data is always inserting '0' index.

But, When I use following code it is moving but data is inserting at last index.

```
   [thePlot insertDataAtIndex:[array count]-1 numberOfRecords:1];
```

Could you please help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of those methods change the data that the plot already has. To make things move, adjust the `xRange` of the plot space. This is how the "Real Time Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app works.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I don't want to change the x-axis range. X-axis is fixed that is 0 to 1800. When the number of plots reached to 1800 I want remove the last pilot.I want plot at index 0 and move the plot till 1800. Please suggest me.

Comment: The data index is independent of the x- and y- data values on the plot. Inserting a new value in the data array doesn't change the ones that are already there. If you do need to change them, call `-reloadData` to force the plot to reload all of the data points and provide new values in the datasource.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Eric. Thanks a lot for your reply. I solved the issue. Thanks again ....